# How to influence code-completion suggestions in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I like the time-saving convenience of using code completion with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> in Eclipse.  (I'm currently using Eclipse Oxygen.)  However, sometimes I wish I could change the order of suggestions within the drop-down menu.  In particular, I get frustrated with the suggestions when I use completions with Apache's `Logger` class:

[image: Logger debug suggestions]

The suggestion at the top of the list is a `debug` variant with nine arguments.  Because Eclipse *usually* provides me the best choice first, I often accidentally choose the nine-argument variant, instead of the single-argument variant that is almost always what I want.  Then I have to undo the selection I made, and do it over.  This may waste several seconds of my life.

Is there any way to get Eclipse to put the one-argument variant at the top of the list?  I can't imagine that too many people prefer calling `debug` with nine arguments.

Comment: THIS! So much this! Currently, I write log.(info|debug|trace) practically every minute and ALWAYS have to correct that, because even if I write the whole line by hand, Eclipse autocompletes to this $/&%$% long prototype, wasting 5 seconds immediately and breaking my flow, so it's way more wasted time per day... and the sorting options do not help. And setting filters does not help either, because they don't apply to the argument list.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not possible.
But there are few option you could try.

Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist`.

There you'll find 2 sorting and filtering options - 'by relevance' and 'alphabetically'.

Comment: It seems like "relevance" is the correct choice for me.  I wonder how Eclipse determines relevance.  The one-arg method call would seem more relevant than the nine-arg version.

Comment: lol!! Eclipse is not providing a facility to determine the relevance. :-)